# Two factor groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $N_1, N_2$ be two isomorphic subgroups of $G$. To show that the factor groups $G/N_1$ and $G/N_2$ are isomorphic.

What I tried so far is the following. Let $g$ be the isomorphism from $N_1$ onto $N_2$. We define
$f:G \to G/N_2$ by $f(x) = g(x)g(N_1)$ for all $x $ in $G$.

However I am unable to show $f$ is onto group homomorphism. May be my approach is incorrect. Please guide me.

Thanks in well advance.

Comment: Is this really true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to prove is false.  Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$.  Consider $N_1= \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{0\}$ and $N_2 = \{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \langle 2 \rangle$.  Then $N_1 \cong N_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ yet $G/N_1 \cong \mathbb{Z_4}$
and  $G/N_2 \cong \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$.

Comment: I understood. Nicely presenetd the counter example. Thank you so much. One doubt: what is we consider that $N1  $ and $N2$ are two equal cyclic groups ? In such case, if $a$ be a generator of $N1$ then $N2$ must be generated by $a^r$ for some positive integer $r$ coprime with order  of $a$. Hence $N1 $ and $N2$ are same and hence $G/N1$ is same as $G/N2$. Please modify if I made any mistake

Comment: If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are equal then obviously $G/N_1=G/N_2$. That is trivial.

Comment: ohh my bad!!! :-D i should have seen it. thanks a lot

Comment: Suppose both $N1$ and $N2$ are cyclic subgroups of same order of $G$. Will then $G/N1$ be isomorphic to $G/N2$ ?

Comment: @KON3  Again, no, and you can use the same trick in my original example.  Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ and consider $N_1 = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{0\}$ and $N_2 = \{0\} \times \langle 2 \rangle$.  Both $N_1$ and $N_2$ are cyclic of order $2$ yet their quotients are $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ respectively.  Note that all my examples use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ isn't cyclic.

Comment: This will be true when $G$ is cyclic, since all quotients of a cyclic group are cyclic and there is a unique cyclic group (up to iso) of any given size.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for clearing my doubt. Can you suggest me what should I modify in the statement ?